# How do I auntheticate into this website using NSURLSession?

Tags: ios, http, nsurl

I'm trying to log in to [Mistar](https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/PortalMainPage) using NSURLSession (or AFNetworking, or something else, whatever seems appropriate) 
Heres my code:

```
- (void)loginToMistar {

   //Create POST request
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

   //Create and send request
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/Login"];
   NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Pin=%@&Password=%@", @"20005012", @"wildcats"];
   NSData * postBody = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   [request setHTTPBody:postBody];

   [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

   NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];

   [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        // do whatever with the data...and errors
        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil) {
             NSString *loggedInPage = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
             NSLog(loggedInPage);
        }
         else {
            NSLog(@"error");
        }
    }];
}
```

It logs in, and returns the HTML content of the page saying my login *failed*. So it succeeds in passing a request, but it fails and gives me the `Error with login` page instead.

What's wrong with my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are posting data to server you must call this method for your NSMutableURLRequest object-

[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

The default HTTP method is "GET". Read more-

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableURLRequest/setHTTPMethod:

Comment: Ok, so I create a `urlRequest`, and put what as the POST content?

Comment: Hope your are familiar with "GET" vs "POST" methods for client and server interaction. When sending data to server, in your case email&password. You need to add setHTTPMethod:"POST" in your NSMutableURLRequest. This tells the server to read the posted data.
I also noticed that you are using two different objects "NSMutableURLRequest *request" and "NSURLRequest *urlRequest". Why?

Comment: @vforvendetta It's correct that a POST request must be setup accordingly with the request. However what you are stating about "sending data" is not generally correct. A GET request may send _certain_ data to the server as well, for example credentials. Those can be incorporated into the URI query component. In fact sending credentials via the query component, is the ONLY way to achieve authentication that works with the NSURLConnection convenience class method `sendAsynchronousRequest:...`. A login feature using a POST request, whose credentials are part of the body, won't work that way.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Oh yeah you are right GET requests may send data. But on the server side the queries are handled based on GET and POST method fields. It's possible that AndrewSB's password web service requires POST method field. Which is why it succeeds in passing a request but fails to authenticate.
I faced exact same issues while developing my app. Setting POST method worked like charm!

Answer (score 0):

If you use the *convenience* API of `NSURLConnection`, `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` and require authentication, you MUST pass the credentials within the URL in some appropriate way. This implies that the server supports this naive authentication method.

In order to have more control over the authentication process, you should use `NSURLSession` or `NSURLConnection` using delegates.

See also: [sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW10)

and [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i)

Comment: Alright, so I know how to do it as a `.php`, right here  `<form
action="https://mistar.oakland.k12.mi.us/novi/StudentPortal/Home/Login"method="post">
     <input type=text name="Pin">
     <input type=password name="Password">
     <input type="submit" id="LoginButton">
     </form>`